# Remove comment appended in .csv

Tags: codeigniter, csv, expressionengine, export-to-csv

I use the following :

```
$this->EE->load->dbutil();
$data = ltrim($this->EE->dbutil->csv_from_result($query, ';', "\r\n"));
$this->EE->load->helper('download');
force_download("export.csv", $data);
```

At the beginning of the file, there is this :

{!-- ra:0000000075fc0e470000000024329d6b --}

How can I get rid of that ?

Comment: That comment is injected by the EE parsing engine, normally I get it when I have an invalid conditional in a template. Odd how it's returning from a DB query. Other (unrelated) examples: https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/20552 or https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/246223

Answer (score 0):

try this

`$data = preg_replace('/{!--(.*)--}\r\n/Uis', '', $data);`

if you are sure, this line is exlusively in the first line of your data String you can try the following

```
if (!empty($data) && stristr($data, "{!--"))
{
    $arrData = explode("\n\r",$data);
    unset($arrData[0]);
    $strData = implode("\n\r",$arrData);
}
echo $strData;`
```

Comment: This does not work, but it fails better ! The comment is removed from first cell and has now it's own line (1)

Comment: i've adjusted my answer

Comment: my answer was simply bad - try again

Comment: do me a favour please - post the first 5 lines of your output

Comment: I'm sorry, the code outputs customers list, it's strictly confidential.

Comment: i extended the answer with another alternative - this should work under the given circumstance

Comment: you say your data are confidential - just replace this data with chunk
i need to see, how your created data csv string looks like